# Using the GCM service to communicate between 2 applications

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create 2 applications that communicate by the GCM service.
Let's assume that I'm trying to sends string from app A to B and then from B to A.

I'm very new to the GCM service and I'm alittle bit confused. Every time you see myApiCode I replaced it in my original code with the api code.Here is the A code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private final String myApiKey = "903137756997";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, "myApiCode");
        } else {
          Log.v("INFORMATION", "Already registered");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here is the GCMIntentService:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
{
    private final String myApiKey = "903137756997";

    public GCMIntentService()
    {
        super("123");
    }
            ...
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
        System.out.println("123123123123");
    }
            ...

}
```

That code that I've attached would be app A and now I will attach the code of app B:

The following code is a service called from the main activity:

```
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
    Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
    Result result = null;
    try {
        result = sender.send(message, "123", 5);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
         String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
         if (canonicalRegId != null) {
           // same device has more than on registration ID: update database
         }
        } else {
         String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
         if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
           // application has been removed from device - unregister database
         }
        }
}
```

I have to mention that both of the apps are running without exceptions but looks like nothing happens.. I guess I have done something wrong with the keys because I still can't understand how app B will find app A.

Comment: Hi, Please check following:

 1. After GCM registration, next time do you get this line executed: Log.v("INFORMATION", "Already registered");
 2. You are using your project ID here: super("123"); Right?

Comment: The 123 is not my project id, should I use my project id in there?

Comment: I changed the string inside the super to my project id and I putted breakpoints in the onMessage method and it's never triggered.. there is a key that im seding through this line: sender.send(message, "123", 5); but on the other app I never use that key "123" and I think I should but I don't know where.. maybe thats why nothing happens

Comment: Here you need to use registration id of the recipient device. Check "send" method in http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.html

Comment: How can I know the "registration id of the recipient device" of a certain device?

Comment: How we do is, we send registration id and an unique device id to server which can then send GCM message to specific devices. You may also want to upload this information on some server (some static IP to upload info). Sender application can query the server to get registration id of a device.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, I don't have a REAL server in here.. I have 2 phones which is running 2 applications that needs communicate with each other, no server involved.(you may treat each phone as a server since it needs to receive GCM messages and also to send). I know what is my registration id but what is the "id of a device" ?

Comment: GCM (or C2DM as called earlier) is designed to send Cloud to Device message. Here you are trying to do Device to device. This will require some work-around. Will think about what workaround can work here.

Comment: I don't understand something.. what should be then the "normal" GCM conversation?? By your words I understand that DEVICE - > SERVER, SERVER - > DEVICE. Can you explain a little bit more about the server?does it can be a phone?normal java code on a PC? thanks.

Comment: GCM is only Server to Device. We use HTTP for device to server. To send GCM message we make a request from our server to Google server. Though, I believe, your use-case can work with some workaround. e.g. with a accessible datastore. Will write more on this.

Comment: So the server is GOOGLE and I got 2 application that work that way: ap1 -> google, google -> ap2 so I actually need to code only ap1 and ap2 since the server is google.. and that's what I just did(it's not working yet but that's the plan). You agree with me? and really thanks for keep answering to me! appreciated!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25328/discussion-between-sangharsh-and-imri-persiado)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the onRegistered method in GCMIntentService. This will be called when the GCM server returns a registration ID that was prompted by your call to GCMRegistrar.register.

Your implementation of this method should upload the String argument to a server you control, and the server can then send out messages targetting the ID you uploaded.

Also you should not push messages directly between apps this way, because it will require you to ship your private API key out in the app package in order to send messages.

Comment: "Also you should not push messages directly between apps this way", then in which way?since that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Create a simple server that will accept messages from the app, and send them to the other app. This way, your always on server can handle updates to the phone's registration ID, and you can keep your API key private on the server.

Comment: Sounds good but to accept messages it has to implement the GCM right?so it needs to be an android application -> celephone device, doesn't sounds like a server to me. So is there any other way to accept those messages?

Comment: You can't create a reliable network via GCM without an always-on server. You need to have it available to get new registration IDs because they can change over time and expire.

Comment: BAH! That stinks! I was hoping to use direct device-google-device communication (of small messages) without me having to maintain a server :-( big time sad face